# didFinishWithResult is not getting invoked for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

in buttonpress callback:

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

Delegate Implementation:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
NSLog (@" Inside  MAIL COMPOSER CONTROLLER DELIGATE ");


// Remove the mail view
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When i press cancel button in the MailComposerView, delete is not getting invoked. what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your viewController as a MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate:

   ```
   @interface CurrentViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   ```
2. Set your mailComposer delegate right after instantiation:

   ```
   MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
   mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually make your class a MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: This wouldn't cause the method not to be called; it would just cause a compiler warning at the `setDelegate:` line.

Comment: good call. Aside from that, I do not have any ideas off the top of my head.